# Direct link for PDF files in SkyDrive/OneDrive

Tags: links, onedrive, pdf

I want to make a direct link to a document at SkyDrive, so that I'll see only the PDF at the browser, not any of the SkyDrive chrome.  For example, if you click http://www.cccf-fcsge.ca/wp-content/uploads/RS_94-e.pdf, you will go automatically to the PDF file.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there's not currently a way to directly link to a PDF on SkyDrive.  The closest you can get—using the built-in "Share" link—will instead open it in Office365's online Word viewer, for whatever reason.  You can almost circumvent this by sharing the document, then, in the viewer, grabbing the URL that you ultimately download the PDF from by clicking the "Download" button, but this URL appears to be fairly ephemeral.

You might instead take a look at [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), which has this functionality built-in, and which is free for small accounts.